# Android Picasso - image cannot fully load

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, imageview, picasso

Hi I use Picasso to load image in grid view but the first image seems kind of rare. Below is the screen shot of the images.

[image]

Also, if I click a button that could refresh the grid view, everything works perfect

```
gridview.invalidateViews();
adapter = new CVC(getActivity(), colorImageArrayList, colorImageFileArrayList);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

Code to get image in grid view

```
class CVC extends ArrayAdapter<ImageView> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> colorImageArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> colorImageFileArrayList;

    public CVC(Context c, ArrayList<ImageView> colorImageArrayList, ArrayList<String> colorImageFileArrayList) {
        super(c, R.layout.colorcvc, colorImageArrayList);
        this.context = c;
        this.colorImageArrayList = colorImageArrayList;
        this.colorImageFileArrayList = colorImageFileArrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.colorcvc, parent, false);

        final ImageView viewImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cvc_image);
        ImageView image = colorImageArrayList.get(position);
        if (image == null) {
            String imageFileURL = colorImageFileArrayList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(context).load(imageFileURL).placeholder(null)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .into(viewImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    // replace image in index (position)
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                }
                            }
                    };
        } else
            viewImage.setImageDrawable(image.getDrawable());
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

R.layout.colorcvc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cvc_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cvc_colorname"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your grid item xml .

Comment: updated R.layout.colorcvc xml

Comment: Your image height is had coded make it wrap_content then check .In this way your image won't get stretch or squeeze.

Comment: Same thing happens

Comment: Actually, there is a textview under the image view which height is 15dp. I want to make it simpler, thats why I remove it.

Comment: Change your linear layout height and width to wrap_content use fit() in Picasso this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **scaleType** on image view if you want to load it with full size .But as i said in comment your height is hardcoded so this will result in a stretched image .

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cvc_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To load

```
Picasso.with(this).load(url).placeholder(null)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
```

Output .

[image]

Comment: Um. It still remain the same. I am wondering why it shows perfect when I reload the grid view with all the images available

Comment: Add the screen shot of your grid view which has wrong loaded images .

Comment: Same view as the one I uploaded. It only happens in the first image and I just see if I swipe the grid view back and forth, the first image works well

Comment: You made ImageView width 100dp why?In this way image will get Squeezed cause your image on url is of apporx   5:1 ratio . Make it match_parent.

Comment: If I set match_parent in ImageView and LinearLayout, same thing happens and the space between images is so large

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageFileURL).placeholder(null)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit().centerCrop()
                .into(viewImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                // replace image in index (position)
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                            }
                        }
                };
```

You can also use only fit(). But centerCrop() is used to avoid stretched image. 
You can also use resize function like

```
.resize(600,200) //pixel size dimensions
```

Comment: It still remain the same

Comment: try .centerInside() @PakHoCheung

Comment: same thing. I am wondering why only the first image has this issue